# Where can you download a chm version of the JPA 2 API Javadocs?

Tags: java, jpa, javadoc

I'm tired of navigating Oracle's joke of a website! Where do we go for JPA docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it here in the J2EE chm download. Much easier to navigate and search through than a lousy html page, faster than using Google, and especially easier if you're forced to develop on a secure network w/o Interwebs.

http://www.allimant.org/javadoc/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Um, I don't think chm is a preferred format for javadoc. [here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=javadoc+to+chm&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_en___BG265&ie=UTF-8) you can pick a converter, if you insist so much.

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html) is the html javadoc

Comment: Hehe, it's preferred by me. HTML sucks. :p

Comment: @Crusader: So you rather have a proprietary format instead of something that works in just about anything that has electrons moving inside it? Sorry to say but I don't think you'll fit the Java dev mindset :P

Comment: @Esko, dood - I fit in just fine, and if you're developing on Windows, it's more productive. See the answer I posted.

Comment: @Crusader - I'm developing on windows, and googling for javadocs is quite productive

Comment: @Crusader: I can use my 6 year old phone to view javadocs if I feel like it. Can't do that with .chm.

Comment: I didn't come here to start an argument or flamewar about 'proprietary' formats. chm docs that you can search ARE better than Google (see answer I posted) and you're not writing software on your 6 year old phone! Geez...

Comment: Ok I was a little pissy yesterday - I don't deny that coding by Google for Javadocs is productive, but I do maintain that the chm format (try the index tab on the chm dl's I posted to find class names) is a slightly more productive method of getting what you need, particularly in slow or no internet situations.